# Asymptotic distribution of average of non-identically distributed variables

Tags: normality-assumption, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics

I have data from a random variable $X$:

$$\{x_{1},\dots,x_{N}\}$$

I am interested in the **asymptotic distribution** of the sample average $\bar{x}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_{i}}{N}$.

These draws are independent but not identically distributed. They have mean $\mu_{i}$ and variance $\sigma^2_{i}<\infty$. (sorry if notation is not strict enough)

I know the [Lindeberg–Lévy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT) Central Limit Theorem does not hold because moments are not identical. But **assume** the [Lyapunov’s condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT) holds. Then,

$$ \frac{1}{s_{n}}\sum_{i=1}^N(x_{i}-\mu_{i}) \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)  $$

where $s_{n}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_{i}^2 $.

Is there **anything** I can be certain about the sample average? Some sufficient condition? Can I not infer *some degree* of asymptotic normality?

My data support normality of the average. I wonder if there is some theoretical basis behind that, or just mere coincidence.

Comment: If you have Greene, theorem D.19 gives a variant of CLT that only requires independence.

Comment: Lindeberg CLT does not require the same first or second moments. It is a sufficient condition too. In essence, you only need a sequence of RVs whose don't get too big too fast (in the precise sense given in the theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if you have the sample average $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i}$, then using the same "sample average" operator on the individual moments to define $\hat{\mu}=\bar{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2=\overline{\sigma^2}$, your Lyapunov equation becomes
$$\frac{\bar{x}-\hat{\mu}}{\hat{\sigma}/\sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$$
This is essentially the same as the i.i.d. result for the asymptotic sampling distribution of the sample mean.